# What Thunderbolt to USB 3.0 cables/adapters exist for OS X and Mac hardware?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hardware, usb, thunderbolt

I have the Late 2013 Macbook Pro, which has two USB 3.0 ports and two Thunderbolt 2 ports. I currently use both USB 3.0 ports and one TB2 port. I want to connect a third USB 3.0 device to the machine, but I don't want to use a USB splitter on one USB port as I'm concerned the devices would draw too much power from the bus. I have no current use for the second TB2 port and I would love to be able to use it for this purpose.

Browsing extensively online, I've found numerous docks, such as [Belkin's Thunderbolt Express](http://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F4U055/), that connect via a Thunderbolt cable. This would work, but it's an expensive, 'bulkier' solution (and not the one I'm looking for).

I'm aware that a USB 3.0 device wouldn't be able to take advantage of Thunderbolt's I/O speeds, but it's certainly compatible, which is all I'd need. After all, Apple even sells a [Thunderbolt to Firewire Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD464ZM/A/apple-thunderbolt-to-firewire-adapter). I also know that Thunderbolt is not only used for digital video purposes (along with the TB > Firewire option, there exists [Thunderbolt External Hard Drives](http://store.apple.com/us/product/HA384ZM/A/lacie-1tb-rugged-usb-30-thunderbolt-series-hard-drive)).

There are almost no Thunderbolt to USB 3.0 cables/adapters on the market. I'd think this hardware would be more prevalent given the prominence of USB devices out there. What adapters are available for OS X?

Comment: Apple has released [Thunderbolt3/USB-C to Thunderbolt 2/1 adapter](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter) for $29. It will require to use USB-C connector from your external devices, but other than that it looks more compatibility-promising than any third-party connectors.

Comment: @yurkennis I believe that adapter allows you to connect TB 2 external devices > Mac USB C port, not the other way around...additionally only the newest line of Macs use USB C, so it's still not viable adapter for the 99% of Mac users who remain dependent on USB 3.0 external devices. So, unfortunately still no USB 3.0 > TB 2 adapter from Apple. The third party Kanex adapter is unreliable...Still no good option.

Comment: Quote from the official product page: "As a bidirectional adapter, it can also connect new Thunderbolt 3 devices [=>any USB-C as well] to a Mac with a Thunderbolt or Thunderbolt 2 port."

Comment: @yurkennis okay, that makes sense. the male end is USB C and the female TB2, so I guess you'd just flip it by using an additional TB2 cable? at any rate, it's not a USB 3/2 adapter.

Comment: Not an USB-_A_ female adapter, to be precise.

Answer (score 7):

As a matter of fact "Kanex" the only company I know of that offers "true" adapters put their [Thunderbolt to eSATA + USB 3.0 adapter](http://www.kanex.com/thunderbolt-esata) on the market [18 hours ago](https://www.facebook.com/kanexproducts), at a price point of 69.95$

Comment: The Kanex USB 3 adapter would not work with USB 3 external hard drives that I bought it for so I had to return it. Make sure the place you buy it from has a decent return policy.

Comment: Does someone have real-life numbers for transfer speed, e.g. copying a few thousands files around 10 MB each from external disk to `dev/null`?

Comment: @Nemo are you looking for benchmarks comparing Thunderbolt to USB 3.0 or benchmarks for the Kanex adapter?

Comment: the adapter (or any Thunderbult to eSATA adapter really)

Comment: the link seems to have broken, could this be fixed?

Comment: @think123 done.

Answer (score 7):

Thunderbolt and USB are quite different protocols, so you can't just use a cable -- it would need to have active electronics in it to convert between the protocols. And that means it would cost a lot more than a cheap commodity USB hub and so no one would buy it -- they'd just get a hub instead. If you're concerned about the power drain, get a powered USB hub.

Comment: As a matter of fact it is [not uncommon at all](http://www.panic.com/blog/the-lightning-digital-av-adapter-surprise/) for Apple adapters to contain a whole lot more than basic cables. Prices are also usually dominated by the market.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Thunderbolt and Firewire are also very different protocols, as is Thunderbolt/Ethernet. Yet, both adaptors are sold by Apple despite the fact the USB3 connections are much more widely used now than either firewire cables or ethernet cables among notebook users.

Answer (score 6):

I also ended up looking for good solutions. Thunderbolt 2 supports **20 Gb/s**. So it could provide enough reserves for a real usb 3 hub where every port could finally run **5 Gb/s** = **640 MB/s**.

As a single SSD already exceeds the speed of a USB 3 connection, we should not put them through a USB 3 Hub bottleneck to not enforce slowing the transfer rates down.

Actually there are some companies that already considered these issues:

- Highpoint offers an Thunderbolt 2 to 4 port USB3 Hub http://www.highpoint-tech.com/USA_new/series_Thunderbolt_Overview.htm, a dock with 2 SAS Ports and a dock with 3 PCI card slots & 4 SSD bays etc.
- Sonnet has a great Dock with an USB 3 HUB & 2 SSD bays http://www.sonnettech.com/product/echo15prothunderboltdock.html and some other good thunderbolt docks with PCIe card slots for USB3 etc.

Other good manufacturers to check out:

- Promise
- OWC
- G-Technology

All in all going for thunderbolt 2 is always on the much more expensive side of the table.

Answer (score 1):

So, I believe the main reason these cables/adapters don't exist is explained in your question, actually. That is, the fact that many, if not all, devices that come with a Thunderbolt port, also already have one or more USB 3.0 ports.

If your primary concern is simply power draw on the bus, I'd recommend simply buying a [powered USB 3.0 hub](http://www.amazon.com/s/?_encoding=UTF8&camp=1789&creative=390957&field-keywords=powered%20usb%203%20hub&linkCode=ur2&tag=sa-3993-yq-20&url=search-alias%3Daps&linkId=DQYYQN7ZFLLLT3XH).

Comment: "devices that come with a Thunderbolt port, also already have one or more USB 3.0 ports"... except, of course, a couple of years' worth of Apple products, that came with a Thunderbolt port, but still only had USB 2, such as the Mac Mini, iMac and Macbook models of 2011-2013.

Comment: @RCross Mac mini 2012 has USB 3 ports, not USB 2. I don't know about the other devices in your list.

Comment: Macbook pro late 2011 has 2 USB 2 ports and Thunderbolt, no USB 3 :(

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my problem. I've got an eight port USB hub by Akasa, self powered. I connected four controllers, a sound card and two liscenses to it, while I use an USB 3.0 hub for my external drives. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbolt T2 and USB3 are compatible as Apple device components. Market-place adapters may no work so well. Say you want to swap data from your Mac to the HP-PC business customer.

Apple-only T2 [HighPoint RocketStar](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/985459-REG/highpoint_5212_2_bay_thunderbolt_10gb_s_storage.html) with 10 Gbps data transfer is no help, because half-speed PC's lack Thunderbolt technology. Universal UB3 [StarTech STSDOCK2U33](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1058320-REG/startech_sdock2u33_usb_3_0_dual_sata.html/prm/alsVwDtl) may 'seem' more promising. Consider that fact that Mac/PC swap drive formatting is very tenuous.

Assuming anyone wants an external drive dock for a Mac, the only pro for half-speed StarTech over faster RocketStar is saving $136… Forget the swappable desktop drive dock idea, if possible. Why swap out data using a drive dock? USB is the best way for Mac/PC users to swap and co-produce compatible Microsoft Office and Adobe Creative Cloud data files.

[Can you swap a external hard drive between Mac and pc without affecting it?](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120119134229AAmK0N0)