# How to make my late 2011 MBP compatible with USB 3.0?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, hardware, hardware-recommendation

Maybe an ExpressCard?

Is that the way I should do it?

My ports look like [this](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp644):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Thunderbolt Dock

You can use a **Thunderbolt dock / docking station**. I have added one to my 2011 Mac mini which has no USB 3.0 ports.

There are many docks available and most of them offer USB 3.0 ports.

Keep in mind that, as far as I know, all docks **require an external power source** (wall plug), but there are some that don't need one.

Please let me know if this answers your question.

This is the product I use:

Belkin Thunderbolt Express Dock for about $200, the predecessor of this version:

http://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F4U085/

Pay attention whether or not a Thunderbolt cable is included. A single cable costs between $30-50.

---

### Thunderbolt to USB adapter

Instead of a Thunderbolt dock you can also buy a TB to USB 3.0 adapter. Kanex produces one that also supports eSATA. However, you **won't be able to connect any devices that need to draw power to operate**. Think external 2.5" HDDs/SSDs or USB hubs:

[Kanex Thunderbolt to eSATA + USB 3.0 Adapter, $80](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/HGC82ZM/A/kanex-thunderbolt-to-esata-usb-30-adapter)

Comment: Can I suggest it may be worth also mentioning the docking station you have used (brand/model) and maybe including a link (if one exists).

Comment: Sure, I added the name and a link to the product. I didn't want to make it look like an ad for a specific product/manufacturer. ;-)

Comment: Wowee! Wasn't aware it was that expensive. Too bad mine wasn't a 2012 :p

Answer (score 3):

It won't be cheap! Thunderbolt and USB are different interfaces, so active electronics need to exist in the adapter. One of the most recommended options is [this adapter from Kanex](http://www.kanex.com/thunderbolt-esata).

A few other companies offer similar products at slightly higher price points.

For more information on your question, I'd look at [this Ask Different thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136143/what-thunderbolt-to-usb-3-0-cables-adapters-exist-for-os-x-and-mac-hardware).